# Jmxtrans Config for multiple queries to the same Writer

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, jmxtrans

While setting up metric reporting for Apache Kafka to ElasticSearch with jmxtrans, we have written a configuration file that queries about 50 metrics.

The queries are as follows:

```
{ 
  "obj" : "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=TotalFetchRequestsPerSec", 
  "outputWriters" : [ { 
    "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.elastic.ElasticWriter", 
    "connectionUrl": "http://elasticHost:9200" 
  }] 
}
```

Since there are so many of them all writing to the same destination, is there a way in the config file to shorten this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to be more precise in your MBean path - 
`kafka.server:name=TotalFetchRequestsPerSec,topic=MyCoolTopic,type=BrokerTopicMetrics`

Take a look on [this one](https://github.com/Stackdriver/jmxtrans-config-stackdriver/blob/master/jmxtrans/google-cloud-monitoring/json-detect-instance/kafka.json) as a great example - `jmxtrans` supports `resultAlias` as well.

Here you can find a list of [Kafka MBeans](https://gist.github.com/thbkrkr/77c8f6f9a301d7b16555726793af8301#file-list-rb-L291) which could become handy for you.